# ASP.NET Validators - checking if the sum of two textbox's equals a certain value

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

Basically, I have 2 textbox's which the user enters currency/numeric values - I want to have a validator that checks if the values in these box's add up to make another value. Is there a built in validator for this or would I have to use a custom validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a custom validator for that. There exist no standard validators in ASP.NET that do the sum checking you require.

See also:

- http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/custom-validator
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k(v=vs.71).aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/aspnetvalidation.aspx

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

if bothe values are required : 
 **so 2 of**

```
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="VAL_Req_Pass" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TXT_Password"
                        Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="User">Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

and one of :

```
 <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server"   ValidationGroup="User" 
    ErrorMessage="Password does not match"
    ClientValidationFunction="passwordMatch" 
    ControlToValidate="TXT_Password"
      Display="Dynamic" >
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

which has js function that checks if equal...